# Pass value using button from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning to use React and I have a problem about how to pass the id using a button.

I have recover data for my fetch from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

My js page:

```
handleClick(){
    alert("ALERT " + this.props);
}


render(){
    const listMeetings = this.props.meetings.map((meeting) => 
    <li key={meeting.id}>{meeting.name}
    <button key={meeting.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(meeting.id)} value={meeting.id}>{'Details'}</button>
    </li>);
    return(
        <div>
                   <ul>{listMeetings}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

So at the moment I have a list of name and a button, immediately next to each name.
What I would to do is to pass the id of every name, when the button is clicked (at the moment I would print only an alert with the id.

With my code, I have understand that I pass all the array (so I have 10 object).

How can I do? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your `handleClick` you pass the `meeting.id` as a param but it's missing in the functions declaration

```js
handleClick(id){
  alert("ALERT " + id);
}


render(){
  const listMeetings = this.props.meetings.map((meeting) =>
    <li key={meeting.id}>{meeting.name}
      <button key={meeting.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(meeting.id)} value={meeting.id}>{'Details'}</button>
    </li>);
  return(
    <div>
      <ul>{listMeetings}</ul>
    </div>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: @Jack23 it happens to all, don't worry

Answer (score 1):

Try anonymous function version instead:

```
handleClick = (id){
    alert("ALERT " + id);
}

render(){
    const listMeetings = this.props.meetings.map((meeting) => 
    <li key={meeting.id}>{meeting.name}
    <button key={meeting.id} onClick={(id) => this.handleClick(meeting.id)} value={meeting.id}>{'Details'}</button>
    </li>);
    return(
        <div>
                   <ul>{listMeetings}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```